# Ubuntu 13.04, Mounting 2nd HDD, lost home directory

Tags: 13.04, mount, home-directory, fstab, data-loss

I hope someone can help.
I installed a 2nd HDD, set up 2 partitions on it.

I set up both partitions to mount automatically in /etc/ftsab.

One of the partitions has a mount point of my home directory /home/nick

Trouble is, I forgot to copy everything from the original /home/nick before testing my /etc/fstab by rebooting. (Yes, I'm an idiot). Now I cannot log in (it just bounces back to the login screen), and when I go to a terminal (ctrl+alt+f1) and log in there, my home dir is empty.
When I comment out the changes in /etc/fstab, I still cannot log in.
I even created a new user, and cannot log in with that either.

My questions:

Is there any way of recovering my lost home directory?

How can I unbrick my system?

thanks...

Comment: You just mounted another filesystem on top of a directory. Nothing to worry about - unmounting the filesystem will make your files visible again.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to mount both the old and the new home directory *without* logging in as "nick". As `root` in a rescue shell:

1. Create two directories like `/mnt/old-home` and `/mnt/new-home`.
2. Change `/etc/fstab` to mount the home directories on these directories.
3. `mount -a`
4. Move the files.
5. Unmount both directories.
6. Change `/etc/fstab` to use `/home/nick` instead of `/mnt/new-home`.
7. `mount -a`
8. Exit the rescue shell and tell Ubuntu to boot normally.